# How do I access the 20th anniversary level?

Tags: diablo-iii

> DIABLO III PATCH 2.4.3 - V2.4.3.42336
>
> > New Feature: 20th Anniversary Event
> >
> > A mysterious group of Cultists is stirring up trouble! Hunt them down in Adventure Mode to uncover clues that reveal a portal into Tristram’s past, and rediscover the terrifying darkness that took hold of the town so many years ago…

Where are the cultists that trigger this "The Darkening of Tristram" event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no cultist requirement to access the retro-vision levels. I think they just drop stuff to hint at where you have to actually go to access those levels.

If you don't have access to adventure mode. All you have to do is kill the final boss in act 5. It is fairly easy to find someone who is willing to do this for you.

All you have to do is go to old Tristram town (act 1 waypoint the old ruin in adventure mode).

Comment: Just to clarify in case the asker gets confused, there is a portal in old Tristram near the well in the center of the area that will take you to the event. Also, the cultists that are mentioned drop "page" items that allow you to get a unique character portrait frame as part of the event, but as mentioned, this is optional.